# Task WhenAll Method Get List of Completed Tasks for Azure ServiceBus Send Bulk Messages

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, multitasking, azure-servicebus-queues

I have written a Code below to send Bulk Messages to Azure Service Bus but I am getting Error in between and I wanted to know the list of Ids that are Pushed to Azure Service Bus.

```
public async Task ProcessProfile(NIFFUNDbContext dbContext)
{
    List<Task> concurrentTasks = new List<Task>();
    queueClient = new QueueClient(sbConnectionString, sbQueueName, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete, RetryPolicy.Default);
    List<int> personIds = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        queueClient.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        var list = dbContext.TpPerson.Include("TpPersonContactInformation").Take(10000).ToList();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var dfObjectMessage = NIF.FUN.Framework.DAL.MSSQL.Converter.TransformToDFMessage(item, ISDObjectTypeEnum.TpPerson, EntityChangeStateEnum.Added, DateTime.Now);

            var message = SB.Converter.ToMessage(dfObjectMessage);
            concurrentTasks.Add(queueClient.SendAsync(message));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
        //await queueClient.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can make the code lot simpler by using sender.SendBatchAsync(list); instead of adding the messages one by one and sending it.
if you are using the newer version sender.sendAsync(list) has a overload to accept list

Comment: @kannangokul the above works for windows.azure library and I am making use of Microsoft.azure.servicebus Library.
can you please suggest a method available in "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Libary.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var concurrentTasks = new List<Task>();
    var succeededMessages = new ConcurrentBag<your entity type>();
    var failedMessages = new ConcurrentBag<your entity type>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // just for the sake of showing iteration
    {
        var entity = <your logic of getting entity>;
        concurrentTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var message = <message from your entity>;
                await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
                succeededMessages.Add(entity);
            }
            catch
            {
                failedMessages.Add(entity);
            }
        }));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize the following snippet to send messages in batch so that if it fails it fails for the entire batch you dont have to worry about which message is failed and its also the suggested approach to send messages in batch.

```
        var messagelist = new List<Message>();
        messagelist.Add(new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test1")));
        messagelist.Add(new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test2")));
        var sender = new QueueClient("connectionstring","entitypath");
        sender.SendAsync(messagelist);
```